# Haskell Lempel Ziv 78 Compression

Tags: haskell

http://pl.wikipedia.org/wiki/LZ78
Here's a polish wikipedia site, but it contains a python code that can be used to check if the haskell code works

I'm using the text from the example:
abbbcaabbcbbcaaac

My problem is that while trace is showing the char/int pairs in correct order, they somehow get messed up in the output list. Can somebody explain what's going on?

This is the correct order:
(0,a)
(0,b)
(2,b)
(0,c)
(1,a)
(3,c)
(6,a)
(5,c)

```
import System.IO  
import Control.Monad
import qualified Data.Map as Map
import Debug.Trace
main = do  
  contents <- readFile "file.txt"    
  print $ compress contents Map.empty 1 "" []
compress :: String -> Map.Map String Int -> Int -> String -> [(Int,Char)]-> [(Int,Char)]
compress (s:x) m i c out = do
    if Map.member (c++[s]) m == False 
        then do 
            if c == ""
                then do
                    let newMap = trace( show s ++ "  0  aaaaaa\n") Map.insert [s] i m
                    compress x newMap (i+1) c (out++[(0,s)])
                else do
                    let newMap = trace(show s ++ "  " ++ show (m Map.! c) ++ "  bbbbb\n") Map.insert (c++[s]) i m
                    compress x newMap (i+1) "" out++[(newMap Map.! c, s)]
        else compress x m i (c++[s]) out

compress s m i c out = compress2 out

compress2 ::  [(Int,Char)]-> [(Int,Char)]
compress2 out = out
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's a parenthesization error:

```
compress x newMap (i+1) "" out++[(newMap Map.! c, s)]
```

parses as

```
(compress x newMap (i+1) "" out) ++ [(newMap Map.! c, s)]
```

But you wanted

```
compress x newMap (i+1) "" (out++[(newMap Map.! c, s)])
```

---

Fun problem, by the way. I tried rewriting your code to make it a little more idiomatic:

```
import System.IO
import Data.Map as M
import Prelude as P

main = do
  contents <- readFile "file.txt"
  print $ compress contents

compress :: String -> [(Int, Char)]
compress = reverse . third . P.foldl step (singleton "" 0, "", [])
  where step (dict, pat, log) char =
          let pat' = char:pat
          in if member pat' dict
            -- `pat'` is already in our dictionary, so
            -- we've previously extended `pat` by `char`, and 
            -- we don't need to record anything
            then (dict, pat', log)
            -- pat' is new to us, so 
            --  * assign it a new id in the dictionary 
            --  * start reading a new pattern
            --  * record it in the log
            else (insert pat' (size dict) dict, "", (dict ! pat, char):log)
        third (_, _, log) = log
```

Comment: sir, you are my hero :)
you can say its my first day with haskell :D